# Linq join get null rows filter with where

Tags: linq, join, null

I have three tables joined. Store, StoreReport and Report.

```
Store table
StoreId 
Storename.

Report table
ReportId
ReportName

StoreReport table
StoreId
ReportId
```

I would like to get all the Stores that haven't filled in a specific report.
So far I have this but it counts those who are connected to other reports also.

```
var reports = from u in db.tblStores
                              join sr in db.tblStoreReports.Where(a => a.ReportId != reportId && !a.Deleted)
                        on u.StoreId equals sr.StoreId into g
                    where !g.Any()
                    select u;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from u in db.tblStores
where !u.StoreReports.Any(a => a.ReportId == reportId && !a.Deleted)
select u
```

You can use `!.Any` to make sure it does not have a `Report` with certain `id`

Comment: Same with this. It returns all of the rows in the table stores. The two that have a report are included. Could it be that it is a many to many relationship?

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data/collection of objects?

Comment: Both of these worked. I realized that the error was in the input data.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simpler? You can use `Where` without a join:

```
var reports = from u in db.tblStores
              where !db.tblStoreReports.Any(sr => sr.StoreId == u.StoreId 
                                               && sr.ReportId == reportId 
                                               && !sr.Deleted)
              select u;
```

Comment: Hmm, this returns all of the rows in the table stores. The two that have a report are included. Could it be that it is a many to many relationship?

Comment: Both of these worked. I realized that the error was in the input data.